# Hubot on Ubuntu: how to enforce enforce working only with HTTPS?

Tags: linux, http, ubuntu, https, hubot

Installed hubot on Ubuntu machine, when run bin/hubot i get the below error.

> network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write
>   EPROTO 3074811648:error:140770FC:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
>   protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794

As I understand this is because the robot tries to make http request while my machine support only https requests.

how can I enforce the hubot to perform only https requests ?

NOTE: I'm behind proxy and configured it in env variable HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY

Full error is:

> npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs"
>   "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "hubot" "hubot-scripts" "hubot-diagnostics"
>   "hubot-help" "hubot-heroku-keepalive" "hubot-google-images"
>   "hubot-google-translate" "hubot-pugme" "hubot-maps"
>   "hubot-redis-brain" "hubot-rules" "hubot-shipit" "--save" npm ERR!
>   node v4.4.4 npm ERR! npm  v3.9.0 npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established,
>   cause=write EPROTO 3074811648:error:140770FC:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
>   protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794: npm ERR! network
>   npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself npm
>   ERR! network and is related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network
>   In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm
>   ERR! network npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make
>   sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See:
>   'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /root/myhubot/npm-debug.log